# Unique Indexes query for HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I've got a query that selects unique indexes from a MySQL DB table:

```
SHOW indexes from [tablename] WHERE non_unique = FALSE and key_name <> "PRIMARY"
```

I am looking to create the equivalent query that works for HSQLDB

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's available in [information_schema.system_indexinfo](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#N11D89)

```
select *
from information_schema.system_indexinfo
where non_unique = false
  and table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
  and table_schem = 'PUBLIC'
  and not exists (select * -- exclude PK indexes
                  from information_schema.system_primarykeys pk
                  where ii.table_cat = pk.table_cat
                    and ii.table_schem = pk.table_schem
                    and ii.index_name = pk.pk_name)
```

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name :) But where is the tablename in this query?

Comment: `system_indexinfo.table_name` contains - surprise - the table name

Comment: Thanks, its is a bit difficult for me to orient in HSQLDB, could you, please, adjust your query to join for system_indexinfo.table_name

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, tthat column is already included in the result because of `select *`

Comment: so I just need to add a where clause? Like "and table_name = [tablename]" ?

Comment: Ah, you want to restrict this to a specific table. Then yes.